# What is an advantage of taking Dummit&Foote definition for 'word'?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a set.

Let $S^{-1}$ be a set disjoint and bijective to $S$.

Set the element in $S^{-1}$ corresponding to an element $a\in S$ as $a^{-1}$.

In wikipedia, a word is simply defined as *a finite product of elements of $S\cup S^{-1}$*

However, Dummit&Foote puts an extra element that is $1$ such that $\{1\}$ is disjoint from $S\cup S^{-1}$.

I don't get the point of adding $1$...

Comment: 1 is defined to be the empty product. You need this for the free group over S to actually be a group (1 is your identity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably $1$ here refers to the null word of zero letters, which is given by convention by the empty product. This word is the identity element of the monoid of words under the operation of concatenation (it satisfies that $1 \cdot w = w = w \cdot 1$ for all words $w$). Probably shortly you'd define the free group on the set $S$ of letters, which is just like the monoid of words except that you'll allow cancellation of adjacent inverse letters, e.g., in the free group, $aa^{-1} = 1$. In the free group, $1$ is its own inverse, whereas elements of $S$ each have distinct inverses in the monoid of words and in the free group on $S$.